# Using Golang to get Windows idle time (GetLastInputInfo or similar)

Tags: winapi, go, idle-timer

Is there an example or method of getting a Windows system's idle time using Go?
 I've been looking at the documentation at the Golang site but I think I'm missing how to access (and use) the API to get system information including the idle time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go's website is hardcoded to show the documentation for the standard library packages on Linux. You will need to get godoc and run it yourself:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
godoc --http=:6060
```

then open `http://127.0.0.1:6060/` in your web browser.

Of note is package `syscall`, which provides facilities for accessing functions in DLLs, including UTF-16 helpers and callback generation functions.

Doing a quick recursive search of the Go tree says it doesn't have an API for `GetLastInputInfo()` in particular, so unless I'm missing something, you should be able to call that function from the DLL directly:

```
user32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll") // or NewLazyDLL() to defer loading
getLastInputInfo := user32.MustFindProc("GetLastInputInfo") // or NewProc() if you used NewLazyDLL()
// or you can handle the errors in the above if you want to provide some alternative
r1, _, err := getLastInputInfo.Call(uintptr(arg))
// err will always be non-nil; you need to check r1 (the return value)
if r1 == 0 { // in this case
    panic("error getting last input info: " + err.Error())
}
```

Your case involves a structure. As far as I know, you can just recreate the structure flat (keeping fields in the same order), but you **must** convert any `int` fields in the original to `int32`, otherwise [things will break on 64-bit Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx). Consult the [Windows Data Types page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the appropriate type equivalents. In your case, this would be

```
var lastInputInfo struct {
    cbSize uint32
    dwTime uint32
}
```

Because this (like so many structs in the Windows API) has a `cbSize` field that requires you to initialize it with the size of the struct, we must do so too:

```
lastInputInfo.cbSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(lastInputInfo))
```

Now we just need to pass a pointer to that `lastInputInfo` variable to the function:

```
r1, _, err := getLastInputInfo.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lastInputInfo)))
```

and just remember to import `syscall` and `unsafe`.

All args to `DLL/LazyDLL.Call()` are `uintptr`, as is the `r1` return. The `_` return is never used on Windows (it has to do with the ABI used).

---

Since I went over most of what you need to know to use the Windows API in Go that you can't gather from reading the `syscall` docs, I will also say (and this is irrelevant to the above question) that if a function has both ANSI and Unicode versions, you should use the Unicode versions (`W` suffix) and the UTF-16 conversion functions in package `syscall` for best results.

I think that's all the info you (or anyone, for that matter) will need to use the Windows API in Go programs.

Comment: I don't even use windows but this was very informative.

Comment: When I try the sampling, I keep getting back 1 for r1. Is that result saying that it's been 1 timer tick since idle, or is it simply returning a boolean true? Should I be getting the dwTime?

(Thank you for the informative explanation, @andlabs. I think I'm on the right path, just missing some key understanding of what information I'm pulling.)

Comment: @BartSilverstrim (sorry for the delay in responding) yes, r1 in this case is the return value from `GetLastInputInfo()`, which [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) represents whether the function succeeded or not. You'll need to check r1, and if nonzero, get `dwTime` out of your structure after the call, which is the value you actually want. (See also the `_Out_` annotation, which indicates that the function returns values there.) If r1 == 0, err will contain the error information (that is, `GetLastError()` is called for you).

Comment: @andlabs Thanks for the clarification! I've been working on the application beyond that and while I didn't think to check r1 for the result before getting the actual tick count from dwTime, I did experiment and get results from that. You've been super helpful and thank you again! I'll have to add a note to go back and add that check for thoroughness later.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding for answer from [andlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408572/andlabs). This is ready for use example:

```
import (
    "time"
    "unsafe"
    "syscall"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    user32            = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    kernel32          = syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    getLastInputInfo  = user32.MustFindProc("GetLastInputInfo")
    getTickCount      = kernel32.MustFindProc("GetTickCount")
    lastInputInfo struct {
        cbSize uint32
        dwTime uint32
    }
)

func IdleTime() time.Duration {
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(lastInputInfo))
    currentTickCount, _, _ := getTickCount.Call()
    r1, _, err := getLastInputInfo.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lastInputInfo)))
    if r1 == 0 {
            panic("error getting last input info: " + err.Error())
    }
    return time.Duration((uint32(currentTickCount) - lastInputInfo.dwTime)) * time.Millisecond
}

func main() {
    t := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    for range t.C {
        fmt.Println(IdleTime())
    }
}
```

This is code print idle time every second. Try run and don't touch mouse/keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use an existing package instead of implementing your own, see the following repo by lextoumbourou:

https://github.com/lextoumbourou/idle

usage example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lextoumbourou/idle"
)

func main() {
    idleTime, _ := idle.Get()
    fmt.Println(idleTime)
}
```

prints the current user's idle time