# What are the sign extension rules for calling Windows API functions (stdcall)? This is needed to call WInAPI from Go, which is strict about int types

Tags: c, winapi, go, interop, stdcall

Oops, there was one thing I forgot when I made [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22950406/3408572), and it's something that I'm both not quite sure on myself and that I can't seem to find information for on MSDN and Google and the Stack Overflow search.

There are a number of places in the Windows API where you use a negative number, or a number too large to fit in a signed integer; for instance, `CW_USEDEFAULT`, `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, `GWLP_USERDATA`, and so on. In the world of C, everything is all fine and dandy: the language's integer promotion rules come to the rescue.

But in Go, I have to pass all my arguments to functions as `uintptr` (which is equivalent to C's `uintptr_t`). The return value from the function is also returned this way, and then I will need to compare. Go doesn't allow integer promotion, and it doesn't allow you to convert a signed constant expression into an unsigned one at compile-time.

Right now, I have a [bit of a jerry-rig](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/c5df1b1afc6980d71de17715868ee2c54aa5cf32/common_windows.go#L64) set up for handling these constants in my [UI library](https://github.com/andlabs/ui). ([Here's an example of what this solution looks like in action.](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/33d417886563dad94b936a791d3512dc1818fe48/sysdata_windows.go#L162)) However, I'm not quite satisfied with this solution; it feels to me like it's assuming things about the ABI, and I want to be absolutely sure of what I'm doing.

So my question is: how are signed values handled when passing them to Windows API functions and how are they handled when returning?

All my constants are [autogenerated](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/4a66f1467bf0ee9a69c0758a53ab6f1425da166d/tools/windowsconstgen.go) ([example output](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/74c851754c52adf74e611bc1533c8eb481439d84/zconstants_windows_386.go)). The autogenerator uses [a C ffi](http://tip.golang.org/cmd/cgo/), which I'd rather not use for the main project since I can call the DLLs directly (this also makes cross-compilation easier at least for the rest of the year). If I could somehow leverage that, for instance by making everything into a C-side variable of the form

```
uintptr_t x_CONST_NAME = (uintptr_t) (CONST_NAME);
```

that would be helpful. But I can't do that without this answer.

Thanks!

#### Update

Someone on IRC put it differently (reformatted to avoid horizontal scrolling):

```
[19:13] <FraGag> basically, you're asking whether an int with a value of -1
                 will be returned as 0x00000000FFFFFFFF or as 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
                 if an int is 4 bytes and an uintptr is 8 bytes
```

Basically this, but specifically for Windows API interop, for parameters passed in, and regardless of uintptr size.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but [syscall_windows.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_windows.go) declares `InvalidHandle` as `^Handle(0)` (and `Handle` is a `uintptr`). So the short answer to "what's my `uintptr(-1)` equivalent" is `^uintptr(0)` (should apply equally on 32 and 64-bit). If there are situations where you need other low-level casting that Go doesn't include in the language, you can do it via unsafe: http://play.golang.org/p/JObvq_X5x0

Comment: Also, you can can create `uintptr` values using wraparound if you [declare them `var` instead of `const` and force them to be computed at runtime](http://play.golang.org/p/SLFS_Xx0wd). I think (size of uintptr)==(size of int) on both windows_386 and windows_amd64 (straightforward to test!) so that's not an issue. You can also [do the wraparound arithmetic yourself (even in constants); this answer shows how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878590/the-maximum-value-for-an-int-type-in-go).

Comment: Your first comment led me to look for what constants in package syscall are < -1; the standard file handles are, and autogenerated code simply takes the constants and does uintptr(int(x)) to them. So I guess that's my answer: have the autogenerator do those casts before writing the output file. I'm not sure how to integrate your comment into the self-answer I'll do once I can find where package syscall's autogenerated code is, but thanks in the meantime! :D

Comment: As for your second comment, @twotwotwo, I did that before switching to the autogenerated constants; I was hoping for a way to avoid that :/

Comment: on second thought I'll just remove the TODOs and just use negConst()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@twotwotwo's comments to my question pointed me in the right direction. If Stack Overflow allowed marking comments as answers and having multiple answers marked, I'd do that.

**tl;dr version**: what I have now is correct after all.

I wrote a program (below) that simply dumped all the constants from package syscall and looked for constants that were negative, but not == -1 (as that would just be `^0`). The standard file handles (`STD_ERROR_HANDLE`, `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`, and `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`) are (-12, -10, and -11, respectively). The code in package syscall passes these constants as the sole argument of `getStdHandle(h int)`, which produces the required file handle for package os. `getStdHandle()` passes this int to an autogenerated function `GetStdHandle(stdhandle int)` that wraps a call to the `GetStdHandle()` system call. `GetStdHandle()` takes the int and merely converts it to `uintptr` for passing into `syscall.Syscall()`. Though no explanation is given in the autogenerator's source (mksyscall_windows.go), if this *didn't* work, neither would `fmt.Println()` =P

All of the above is identical on both windows/386 and windows/amd64; the only thing in a processor-specific file is `GetStdHandle()`, but the relevant code is identical.

My `negConst()` function is already doing the same thing, just more directly. As such, I can safely assume that it is correct.

Thanks!

```
// 4 june 2014
// based on code from 24 may 2014
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "go/token"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/types"
    _ "code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/gcimporter"
)

var arch string

func getPackage(path string) (typespkg *types.Package, pkginfo types.Info) {
    var pkg *ast.Package

    fileset := token.NewFileSet()       // parser.ParseDir() actually writes to this; not sure why it doesn't return one instead
    filter := func(i os.FileInfo) bool {
        if strings.Contains(i.Name(), "_windows") &&
            strings.Contains(i.Name(), "_" + arch) &&
            strings.HasSuffix(i.Name(), ".go") {
            return true
        }
        if i.Name() == "race.go" ||     // skip these
            i.Name() == "flock.go" {
            return false
        }
        return strings.HasSuffix(i.Name(), "_windows.go") ||
            (!strings.Contains(i.Name(), "_"))
    }
    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fileset, path, filter, parser.AllErrors)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for k, _ := range pkgs {        // get the sole key
        if pkgs[k].Name == "syscall" {
            pkg = pkgs[k]
            break
        }
    }
    if pkg == nil {
        panic("package syscall not found")
    }
    // we can't pass pkg.Files directly to types.Check() because the former is a map and the latter is a slice
    ff := make([]*ast.File, 0, len(pkg.Files))
    for _, v := range pkg.Files {
        ff = append(ff, v)
    }
    // if we don't make() each map, package types won't fill the structure
    pkginfo.Defs = make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object)
    pkginfo.Scopes = make(map[ast.Node]*types.Scope)
    typespkg, err = new(types.Config).Check(path, fileset, ff, &pkginfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return typespkg, pkginfo
}

func main() {
    pkgpath := "/home/pietro/go/src/pkg/syscall"
    arch = os.Args[1]

    pkg, _ := getPackage(pkgpath)
    scope := pkg.Scope()
    for _, name := range scope.Names() {
        obj := scope.Lookup(name)
        if obj == nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("nil object %q from scope %v", name, scope))
        }
        if !obj.Exported() {        // exported names only
            continue
        }
        if _, ok := obj.(*types.Const); ok {
            fmt.Printf("egrep -rh '#define[     ]+%s' ~/winshare/Include/ 2>/dev/null\n", obj.Name())
        }
        // otherwise skip
    }
}
```